# kotlin. android. При нажатии открывается не нужный activity

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть следующий layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.logapp.UserAccount">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openScanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/take_scan_qr_code"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.617" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.405"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_value"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.405"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sure_name"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/site_name"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.405"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_value" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sure_name_value"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.405"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sure_name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

И вот следующий:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScannerViewActivity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

При нажатии на кнопку с id openScanner должно открываться окно сканера(второе). Но открывается совершенно другое. Вот код который назначает открытие следующего окна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но он почему то не работает, хотя там явно написано какой активити я хочу открыть
В чем может быть проблема, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: 1) код публикуйте текстом, а не скриншотами. 2) описывайте проблему так чтобы суть была понятна не только вам ("не работает" - это не описание, объясните что именно не так и как должно быть). 3) содержимое макетов здесь лишнее - проблема в логике

Answer (score 0):

Manifest:

```kotlin
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.sandbox">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application ...>
        <activity android:name=".LaunchActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LaunchActivity:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            toActivity(MainActivity::class.java)
        }
    }

    private fun toActivity(cl: Class<*>) {
        val permissionStatus = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)

        if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val intent = Intent(this, cl)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 1)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
       when(requestCode) {
           1 -> {
               if (grantResults.first() == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   toActivity(MainActivity::class.java)
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

Работает. В Манифесте обязательно нужно прописывать все разрешения. Если их нет, то у Вас всегда будет приходить ответ `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`.
На Андройд < 6 разрешения показывают перед установкой.